# Oracle finding last row inserted

Tags: oracle

Let say I have table *my table* has values(which they are varchar):

> values 
>   a
>   o
>   g
>   t

And I have insert a new value called V

> values 
>   **V**
>   a
>   o
>   g
>   t

Is there a way or query that can specify what is the last value was insert in the column ? 
 the desired query : select * from dual where rown_num = count(*) -- just an example 
 and the result will be V

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rows in a table have no inherent order. `rownum` is a pseudocolumn that's part of the select so it isn't useful here. There is no way to tell where in the storage a new row will physically be placed, so you can't rely on `rowid`, for example.

The only way to do this reliably is to have a timestamp column (maybe set by a trigger so you don't have to worry about it). That would let you order the rows by timestamp and find the row with the highest (most recent) timestamp.

You are still restricted by the precision of the timestamp, as I discovered creating a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67557/1); without forcing a small gap between the inserts the timestamps were all the same, but then it only seems to support `timestamp(3). That probably won't be a significant issue in the real world, unless you're doing bulk inserts, but then the last row inserted is still a bit of an arbitrary concept.

---

As quite correctly pointed out in comments, if the actual time doesn't need to be know, a numeric field populated by a sequence would be more reliable and performant; another [SQL Fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f5681/1), and this is the gist:

```
create table t42(data varchar2(10), id number);

create sequence seq_t42;

create trigger bi_t42
before insert on t42
for each row
begin
  :new.id := seq_t42.nextval;
end;
/

insert into t42(data) values ('a');
insert into t42(data) values ('o');
insert into t42(data) values ('g');
insert into t42(data) values ('t');

insert into t42(data) values ('V');

select data from (
  select data, row_number() over (order by id desc) as rn
  from t42
)
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: "You are still restricted by the precision of the timestamp"; so couldn't you use a unique ID instead that increments with every entry? The row with the largest uuid must then be the newest.

Comment: Alex, what if two values are inserted almost at the same time? So would be better to have a number field and increment the number using trigger? Number field can be called as `record_version` and query max of `record_version`.

Comment: Yes, agree with both of you, an ID field populated by the trigger from a sequence would indeed be better. This is useful if you want to know when it was inserted too, but that wasn't the question *8-)